# What do hscale and vscale in the geometry package mean?

Tags: margins, paper-size, geometry

What are `hscale` and `vscale`?
How can I use them?

If I use `geometry` package like the code below, what will happen to the `total body`?

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hscale = 0.6, vscale = 0.5}
```

I didn't understand the use even after reading the [`user manual`](http://ekalavya.imsc.res.in/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) page number = 6, 7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Barring some technical details, using

```
\usepackage{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\geometry{hscale=<hval>,vscale=<vval>}
```

is effectively similar to

```
\geometry{totalwidth=<hval>\paperwidth,totalheight=<vval>\paperheight}%
```

thereby scaling the "total body" with respect to the stock/paper size. Technically, the "total body" could include the space around the text block, which includes the margin space (horizontally), header and footer (vertically), so the above is a small simplification.

Compiling the following minimal example, removing the appropriate comment, you'll notice the same look output by `geometry`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\geometry{showframe,hscale=0.6,vscale=0.5}% First compile (left image)
%\geometry{showframe,totalwidth=0.6\paperwidth,totalheight=0.5\paperheight}% Second compile (right image)
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

The image on the left contains the `hscale` and `vscale` options, while the image on the right contains the equivalent `totalwidth` and `totalheight` settings:

[image: Use of hscale and vscale in geometry package]

There are many equivalences between options that can be specified. For example, `noheadfoot` is equivalent to specifying *both* `nohead` and `nofoot`. These equivalences are usually meant to provide abbreviated package options (that combine other, more specific, choices) and promote ease-of-use.